# Solve differential equation with matrix method

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following IVP:

$$\ddot{x} + 2\dot{x} - 8x = 4$$ subject to the initial values $$x(0) = 0 \\ \dot{x}(0) = 0$$

I am asked to solve it using matrix method (I don't know if it is the correct translation to English, but basically, it wants me to solve this through linear algebra).

I don't have much experience in solving differential equations with linear algebra, but I know how to solve something like a system of equations involving $\frac{dx}{dt}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dz}{dt}$ by using $\dot{X}=AX$ and etc.

Comment: I added more of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could model it like this:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
\dot{x}
\end{matrix}
\right]
+
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & -1 \\
-8 & 2
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
\dot{x}
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
4
\end{matrix}
\right] \iff \\
\dot{u} + A u = b
$$
Then look for $u = e^{-At} v$, which implies $u_0 = v_0$.

This gives $\dot u = -A\,e^{-At} v + e^{-At}\dot v$ and $e^{-At} \dot v = b$, so $\dot v = e^{At} b$ and
$$
v = \int\limits_0^t e^{A\tau} b\, d\tau + v_0
$$
and
\begin{align}
u 
&= e^{-At}\left( \int\limits_0^t e^{A\tau} d\tau\, b + v_0 \right) \\
&= e^{-At}\int\limits_0^t e^{A\tau} d\tau\, b + e^{-At} u_0
\end{align}

Comment: In fact, I am not supposed to use those integrals and stuff, only linear algebra (although one can integrate with matrices...). Actually, I used the equation you suggested, found the solution for the homogeneous equation (i.e., when $b=0$) by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A and used that $x(t)=c_1v_1e^{\lambda _1t}+c_2v_2e^{\lambda _2t}$ and then I found the particular solution and summed up both solutions to get the general solution. Then I is just found $c_1$ and $c_2$ without problems.

Comment: This is a first order DE on two dimensional vectors, so one integration shows up during the general solution. In this case, because $b$ is not time dependent, it would have meant only the integration of the components of $e^{A\tau}$. I have not put effort into solving that, there are some methods for this as well. If you set $b=0$ you avoid that part of course and have to guess a particular solution by some means or variation of constants. My main point was to show how to map a second order DE into two first order equations. But I am happy you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = x'$.
Your equation is equivalent to the system
$$x' = y$$
$$y' = 8x - 2y + 4$$
Now try to transform this two equations in one equation with square matrices of size 2 ($X' = AX +B$).

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as mvw's, but my main problem was in finding matrices A and B. That is why I accepted mvw's answer, which gave me these matrices and then I could look for them already knowing what I should get. Thanks anyway!